# How to select a file from Android Emulator?

Tags: android

These are the codes which appeared to have no error but activity stops when I clicked on the Select File button. I wish to upload a file to Amazon S3 but I have to choose a file before uploading. The File I wish to upload is from "Downloads" of the emulator.
Anyone know what's wrong?

```
  package sit.nyp.edu.sg.filepicker;

  import java.io.File;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FilePicker2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView textFile, textFileName, textFolder;
TextView textFileName_WithoutExt, textFileName_Ext;

private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button buttonPick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonpick);
    textFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfile);
    textFolder = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfolder);
    textFileName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfilename);

    textFileName_WithoutExt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfilename_withoutext);
    textFileName_Ext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfilename_ext);

    buttonPick.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);



        }});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(requestCode){
    case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
            String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
            int lastPos = FilePath.length() - FileName.length();
            String Folder = FilePath.substring(0, lastPos);

            textFile.setText("Full Path: \n" + FilePath + "\n");
            textFolder.setText("Folder: \n" + Folder + "\n");
            textFileName.setText("File Name: \n" + FileName + "\n");

            filename thisFile = new filename(FileName);
            textFileName_WithoutExt.setText("Filename without Ext: " + thisFile.getFilename_Without_Ext());
            textFileName_Ext.setText("Ext: " + thisFile.getExt());

        }
        break;

    }
}

private class filename{

    String filename_Without_Ext = "";
    String ext = "";

    filename(String file){
        int dotposition= file.lastIndexOf(".");
        filename_Without_Ext = file.substring(0,dotposition);
        ext = file.substring(dotposition + 1, file.length());  
    }

    String getFilename_Without_Ext(){
        return filename_Without_Ext;
    }

    String getExt(){
        return ext;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you're using an emulator you will have access to the logcat which will tell you where the problem is (i.e., an exception has a occurred including the line of code that caused it. Post the logcat.

Comment: 01-04 07:03:25.903: E/AndroidRuntime(332): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=file/* }

Is this the error?

Comment: "Is this the error?" Yes, most probably. The answer from nandeesh explains it. You need to install an app on the emulator which gives the option to 'pick' files.

Comment: The codes above are for picking files. But I believe this part "intent.setType("file/*");" is incorrect, hence caused the shut down of emulator after i click on "Select File" Button. Which app should I install to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that, you dont have any file browser apps which can handle get content intent on the emulator, though if you post the log , can come to conclusion clearly.

Comment: 01-04 07:03:25.903: E/AndroidRuntime(332): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=file/* }

Is this the error?

Comment: yes.. so you dont have any file browser apps on your emulator.

Comment: What do you mean by file browser apps? The codes above are for picking files. But I believe this part "intent.setType("file/*");" is incorrect, hence caused the shut down of emulator after i click on "Select File" Button. Which app should I install to resolve this?

Comment: On emulator you could install this one http://www.estrongs.com/en/download.html . I have not tried this for get content intent. But this might work, Usually devices have some kind of file explorer preinstalled.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Eclipse to develop an Android application to upload files to Amazon S3 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723192/how-to-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-from-android). I've finished downloading the file browser app, how do I implement the file inside my Android Emulator?